# Ошибка в запросе на RedBeanPhp

Tags: php, mysql, redbeanphp

Сделал запрос, но он не верный

```
$posts = R::findAll('news' , 'name LIKE ?', %array($data['seach'])%);
```

Помогите понять где ставить знаки процентов.

Answer (score 0):

Как то так...

```
$posts = R::findAll ( 'news', 'name LIKE :name', array(':name'=>'%'.искомое.'%'));
```